# Does O(n^2) mean that the algorithm will iterate the loop n^2 times?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

**Does O(n^2) mean that the algorithm will iterate the loop n^2 times?**

```python
  for i in range(n):
      for j in range(n):
          print(1)
```

**And then if I have the code below which is O(n^2 + 10) does that mean that the algorithm will iterate the loop n^2 + 10  times?**

```python
  for i in range(n):
      for j in range(n):
          print(1)

  for i in range(10):
     print(1)
```

Comment: O(n^2) means an algorithm that takes up to 4 times as long for twice as much input. It is not an exact measure of how many iterations you make.

Comment: A simple nested loop is O(n^2); O(n^2) isn't limited to simple nested loops, though. O(n^2 + 10) is the same as O(n^2); lower order terms don't make a difference.

Comment: _"Is O(n^2) means that algorithm will go throw loop n^2 times?"_ No. _"And then if I have code below O(n^2 + 10) means that algorithm will go throw throw loop n^2 + 10 times?"_ Also no. You can start reading https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: This is purely about computer science terminology: the fact that Python code was used for an example does not make this a question about Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually look at the worst-case or average-case time that an algorithm takes. The algorithms you provided take exactly n^2 and n^2 + 10 steps in every case. But some algorithms have more complex conditions where it is not so easy to tell.

The [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) was invented to limit an algorithm runtime from above. Usually it is analyzed for the worst-case run time. The idea is that mostly polynomial or exponential factors matter and the constants are not that important. A good example are the examples that you provided:
You can say: f(n)=n^2 + 10 = O(n^2), because the +10 does not matter and it is the n^2 that dominates the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The double loop has to go n numbers in the first loop and n numbers in the second loop, therefore, as you said, speed is `O(n^2)`. However, the +10 is negligeable, but yes O(n) which means it is linear, speed will get higher with higher n linearly. Not the more the n grows the worse it gets